# Angular with Coffeescript: why my method are executed?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I'm an angular beginner, and coming from Ruby I choose to use Coffescript instead of JS. I'm using ng-classify to define my controller, services and Factory with Coffeescript classes, but I cannot understand what is wrong.

I have my code in this [github repo], but I try to explain here my issue.

I have this controller

```
class Setting extends Controller
  constructor: (@DataService,$log) ->
    @examType = @DataService.getObject('setting_examtype') || { checked: false }
    @settingList = @DataService.getObject('setting_list') || [
                    { text: 'Dai precedenza a domande sbagliate', checked: false },
                    { text: 'Dai precedenza a domande mai fatte', checked: false },
                    { text: 'Mostra subito la soluzione', checked: false }
                  ]
    @questionPossibility = [10,20,30,40,50]
    @questionNumber = @DataService.get('question_number') ||  30
    return

  examTypeChecked: () =>
    @DataService.setObject('setting_examtype',@examType)
    console.log 'examTypeChecked'
    return

  settingListChecked: () =>
    console.log 'settingListChecked'
    @DataService.setObject('setting_list',@settingList)
    return

  questionNumberChecked: () =>
    console.log 'questionNumberChecked'
    @DataService.set('question_number',@questionNumber)
    return
```

The compiled version is:

```
(function() {
  var Setting,
    __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

  Setting = (function() {
    function Setting(DataService, $log) {
      this.DataService = DataService;
      this.questionNumberChecked = __bind(this.questionNumberChecked, this);
      this.settingListChecked = __bind(this.settingListChecked, this);
      this.examTypeChecked = __bind(this.examTypeChecked, this);
      this.examType = this.DataService.getObject('setting_examtype') || {
        checked: false
      };
      this.settingList = this.DataService.getObject('setting_list') || [
        {
          text: 'Dai precedenza a domande sbagliate',
          checked: false
        }, {
          text: 'Dai precedenza a domande mai fatte',
          checked: false
        }, {
          text: 'Mostra subito la soluzione',
          checked: false
        }
      ];
      this.questionPossibility = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
      this.questionNumber = this.DataService.get('question_number') || 30;
      return;
    }

    Setting.prototype.examTypeChecked = function() {
      this.DataService.setObject('setting_examtype', this.examType);
      console.log('examTypeChecked');
    };

    Setting.prototype.settingListChecked = function() {
      console.log('settingListChecked');
      this.DataService.setObject('setting_list', this.settingList);
    };

    Setting.prototype.questionNumberChecked = function() {
      console.log('questionNumberChecked');
      this.DataService.set('question_number', this.questionNumber);
    };

    return Setting;

  })();

  angular.module('app').controller('settingController', ['DataService', '$log', Setting]);

}).call(this);
```

As you can see I insert some log statement, and from the console I understand that all my methods are executed. Why? Why `examTypeChecked` is called?

I call it only if someone use a toggle..

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="setting.examType" ng-checked="setting.examTypeChecked()" toggle-class="toggle-calm" ng-true-value="oltre" ng-false-value="entro">Tipo di esame</ion-toggle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it wrong way, your code is fine, use of code is not what you expected

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="setting.examType" ng-checked="setting.examTypeChecked()" toggle-class="toggle-calm" ng-true-value="oltre" ng-false-value="entro">Tipo di esame</ion-toggle>
```

`setting.examTypeChecked()` will be called every time `$digest()` process is triggered, and it's triggered with each change of model, by `$scope.apply()`, `$scope.digest()`, `$timeout()` and few more

Comment: so the error is in ng-checked="setting.examTypeChecked()" ? How can I execute a function when I switch a Ionic Toggle?

Comment: I wouldn't call it `error` it's expected behaviour, whenever model changes the view should be updated (MVC principles), if you want it to get called only on change you might try use `ng-change`

Comment: or you can use `$watch` on your controller for model `setting.examType` and call function when the model has changed, unfortunately I don't know the ionic framework enough to give you ready solution